# If $L$ is the splitting field of a polynomial $f$ over $K$, $r \in M \supset L$ any element. Is $L[r]$ the splitting field of $f$ over $K[r]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, splitting-field

I was studying the proof of the equivalence: "A field extension L : K is normal and finite if and only if L is a splitting field for some polynomial over K" from Ian Stewart's book, and then, he implicitly used the following steatment:

If $L$ is the splitting field of some polynomial $f$ over $K$ and $r_1$ is any element in some extension $M \supset L$. Then $L[r_1]$ is the splitting field of $f \in K[r_1]$.

I was trying to see why this is true. But nothing came to my mind. I know, it seems kind of obvious but I was not able to justify it. My guess is it has something to do with the extension degree in $L : K$. Could someone please help me to understand why?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think he implicitly used that statement, as it is false; could you instead reproduce his argument and identify where you are stuck? Additionally, there are multiple different definitions of normal so it would help to know the one you use. Also, $f$ is a polynomial so it wouldn't be in $K[r_1]$, but rather $K[x]$ for a variable $x$.

Comment: $L$ is $f\in K[x]$'s splitting field iff $L = K(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ where $a_j$ are the roots of $f$. Then $L(r)=K(r,a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ so it is $f\in K(r)[x]$'s splitting field